# RTC source control files

Tags: eclipse, rtc

I worked on a small project a while ago using Rational Team Concert eclipse. I got rid of it when I was finished the project.

I remember we could go to the team view and open the browser to view our team tasks and user stories and files. I have been googling around for that login page so I can see my old project files again but haven't had any luck.

Does anyone know where I can access my old project files stored on the source control server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3(!) "Team" view in an RTC client:

- Team artifacts (with the Work Items, Build and Source Control sections for each Project Area)
- Team Organization (with all the members)
- Team Dashboard (with your work items, the event logs and Team Load)

I suspect you need to go to the Team Artifact view, get back your project area and check if you still have your repository workspace there for a given Stream.
If yes, you need to load it again to your disk, creating a local workspace or sandbox, in order to get back your Eclipse project.
If not, create a repo workspace on the right Stream and load it.

[image: Team Artifacts view]

See "[Flow changes cross repositories with Rational Team Concert](https://jazz.net/library/article/535/)" for more on that sequence of operations.