# How to install Team artifacts plugins in the Eclipse IDE, such that I can import or export code from repositories?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, rtc

How to install Team artifacts plugins in the Eclipse IDE, such that I can import or export code from repositories?

Team Artifacts button is not visible in my Eclipse IDE.

I need this to connect the repository to fetch some code of a project.

Answer (score 0):

"Team artifacts" is the name of an [RTC Eclipse plugin view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12927759/6309).
See [this thread for illustration](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/150335/how-does-one-get-to-team-artifacts-view-via-rtc-web-client):

That would involve downloading the Eclipse client through the [rational-team-concert/releases/6.0.3](https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/6.0.3) page.

As [described here](https://jazz.net/library/article/190):

> The Team Artifacts view is an Eclipse view within Jazz that presents a hierarchy of heterogeneous elements that are provided from contributed domains.
>   Domains can also be presented within the Artifacts part of a Project Area or Team Area editor.

[image: https://jazz.net/library-content/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/TAN.png]